# C# DataSet from SQL Server and relations

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, relationship

When filling a `DataSet`, how to get the relationships from the database server? I have a relationship in the server.

I mean, I do not have to create relationships in the code, just get it from the database and save automatically into the `DataSet`.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string sqlConString = @"Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS2012;Database=xxx;User Id=xxxxx;Password = xxxxx; ";

using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sqlConString))
{
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1 ;SELECT * FROM table2", sqlCon);
    da.Fill(ds);
    ds.Relations.Add("relation", ds.Tables[0].Columns["ob_ID"], ds.Tables[1].Columns["ob_ID"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way.

You could query the meta-tables to search for foreign keys between `table1` and `table2` and dynamically add a relation based on the result.   But it's a lot more trouble than it's worth.

Much easier to do the extra work yourself at design time, and look in the server to see what the relations are.